# White pixels on layer edges in compositing

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to composite a scene from multiple layers that I have previously rendered. Then, in compositing, some white (and sometimes colored) pixels are appearing on the edges of those layers, but I can't see them when I'm looking at the layer png alone. Does someone have experienced a similar situation?

[image: Layer in compositing]

[image: Layer png]

Comment: Try these compositing nodes - defocus, despeckle, and dilate/erode.  Cryptomatte may also work better for some individual objects but it has to be enabled in render passes and can be difficult to work with if you haven't used it before.

Comment: Thanks for your help, looks like Despeckle did the trick ! But do you have any idea why those pixels appeared ?

Comment: without knowing more about your workflow I couldn't really say, it could be alpha artifacts from png file format, or something about the alpha over node

Comment: Ooooh yeah I think I figured it out, I rendered the image sequence as PNGs instead of EXRs, probably came from here. Thanks for your help !